# How can I control a browser ( ala Selenium ) with node.js?

Tags: node.js

I've heard of [**soda**](http://thechangelog.com/post/1132927058/soda-selenium-node-js-adapter), but it seems like it requires you to signup and there's a limit on the # of minutes ( free acct / 200 minutes ).

Does anyone know if there's some alternative way to control a browser, or more specifically invoke JS on a web page?

Comment: that's for taking videos cross-platform. You can use soda on your machine

Comment: How would you connect it to localhost:4444 which would be my Selenium browser instance?

Comment: @Alfred - ahhh, https://github.com/LearnBoost/soda/raw/master/examples/google.js thanks.. could you post that as the answer?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

https://github.com/LearnBoost/soda/raw/master/examples/google.js

```
/**
 * Module dependencies.
 */

var soda = require('../')
  , assert = require('assert');

var browser = soda.createClient({
    host: 'localhost'
  , port: 4444
  , url: 'http://www.google.com'
  , browser: 'firefox'
});

browser.on('command', function(cmd, args){
  console.log(' \x1b[33m%s\x1b[0m: %s', cmd, args.join(', '));
});

browser
  .chain
  .session()
  .open('/')
  .type('q', 'Hello World')
  .clickAndWait('btnG')
  .getTitle(function(title){
    assert.ok(~title.indexOf('Hello World'), 'Title did not include the query');
  })
  .clickAndWait('link=Advanced search')
  .waitForPageToLoad(2000)
  .assertText('css=#gen-query', 'Hello World')
  .assertAttribute('as_q@value', 'Hello World')
  .testComplete()
  .end(function(err){
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log('done');
  });
```

Answer (score 6):

[Zombie.js](http://zombie.labnotes.org/) might work for you. It is headless and seems really cool.

Comment: I dont get this headless thing. Even if it works in Zombie's browser it doesn't guarantee that it'll work on FF, IE, Chrome, Safari and Opera.

Comment: You could run the tests that check for functionality and then verify rendering with something else.   I use zombie.js to speed up the verification, but not to replace it completely.

Comment: @mcotton how do you verify rendering? do you mean comparing the html output on zombie.js with the output on an actual browser?

Comment: @ajsie I think this headless thing is more about testing the functionality of your website (e.g. during a big refactor) than testing browser compatiblity.  At least that's why I'm interested in it.

Answer (score 4):

There are actually now Selenium bindings for JavaScript that work with Node.js.

Here are some basic steps to get started:

1. 1 Install Node.js, you can find [the download here.](http://nodejs.org/download/)
2. Make sure you
   have the [latest Chrome driver](http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html) and put it in your path.
3. Use `npm install selenium-webdriver` to get the module added to your project.
4. Write a test, for example:

`var webdriver = require('selenium-webdriver');`

```
var driver = new webdriver.Builder().
   withCapabilities(webdriver.Capabilities.chrome()).
   build();

driver.get('http://www.google.com');
driver.findElement(webdriver.By.name('q')).sendKeys('simple programmer');
driver.findElement(webdriver.By.name('btnG')).click();
driver.quit();</code>
```

I cover how to do this with some screenshots and how to use Mocha as a test driver in [my blog post here](http://simpleprogrammer.com/2014/02/03/selenium-with-node-js/).

Answer (score 2):

Here's a pure node.js wrapper around the java API for selenium's webdriver:

https://npmjs.org/package/webdriver-sync

Here's an example:

```
var webdriverModule = require("webdriver-sync");
var driver = new webdriverModule.ChromeDriver;
var By = webdriverModule.By;
var element = driver.findElement(By.name("q"));
element.sendKeys("Cheese!");
element.submit();
element = driver.findElement(By.name("q"));
assert.equal(element.getAttribute('value'), "Cheese!");
```

Save that in a .js file and run it with node.

The module is a pure wrapper, so things like sleep or synchronous calls are entirely possible.  Here's the current interface of the module:

```
module.exports={
   ChromeDriver:ChromeDriver,
   FirefoxDriver:FirefoxDriver,
   HtmlUnitDriver:HtmlUnitDriver,
   By:new By(),
   ExpectedConditions:new ExpectedConditions(),
   WebDriverWait:WebDriverWait,
   Credentials:UserAndPassword,
   Cookie:Cookie,
   TimeUnits:TimeUnits,
   /**
    * @param {number} amount in mills to sleep for.
    */
   sleep:function(amount){
      java.callStaticMethodSync(
         "java.lang.Thread",
         "sleep",
         new Long(amount)
      );
   }
};
```

You can see an integration test that tests the full capabilities here:

https://github.com/jsdevel/webdriver-sync/blob/master/test/integrations/SmokeIT.js

Answer (score 1):

[wd](https://github.com/admc/wd) is "A node.js javascript client for webdriver/selenium 2"

Comment: Any good place to find tutorial? I cannot run a single wd example because `title` variable is `undefined` error